# A issue occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Using AddPooledDbContextFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

Hello Im having an issue migrating and its saying An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (E
rror while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[GraphQlApiFullStack.Models.AppUser] Lifetime: Scoped Implementati onType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[GraphQlApiFullStack.Models.AppUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'GraphQlApiFullStack.Data.ApplicationDbConte
xt' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore

Can someone please help me thanks.

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using GraphQlApiFullStack.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace GraphQlApiFullStack.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Startup.cs services

````
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "GraphQlApiFullStack", Version = "v1" });
            });

            // We use a pooled Db Context Factory here to avoid issues with graphql concurrency
            
            services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection"));
            });

            services.AddIdentityServices(_configuration);

        }
    ```
````